# ANGULAR - Defining Query Parameteres on the Back button press

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router, query-string

I want to add query parameters (for the previous page) on the back button press in the browser.

For example, program code for adding query parameters while calling a customer-hierarchy component view:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/customer-hierarchy']" [queryParams]="{filterBy: currentActiveFilter}">Details</a>
```

So, how to add query parameters for the previous page which is triggered by clicking the default back button in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with session storage. After every filter update on the table, I store these filters in session storage with this line of code:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('workordersTableFilters', JSON.stringify(this.currentActiveFilter));
```

If I want to load data from session storage:

```
const workordersTableFilters = sessionStorage.getItem('workordersTableFilters');
if (workordersTableFilters != null) {
   //Use loaded data
}
```

PS. There is no external library or import necessary